# What are ellipses (...) used for in a Makefile.am?

Tags: makefile, autotools, libtool

I made a library using libtool a while back.
In my example code, the Makefile.am contains ellipses (...). I don't remember what purpose they serve, and googling around I haven't found an answer. What are they for?

```
ignitech_example_SOURCES = ignitech.cpp …
ignitech_example_dyn_SOURCES = ignitech.cpp …
ignitech_example_LDADD = ../libignitech.la
ignitech_example_dyn_LDADD = -lignitech
example:
        $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) -C .. all
        $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) ignitech_example
        $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) ignitech_example_dyn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elipses do not have any special significance to Automake.  If you put an elipsis in a list of file names, as in the example, then it will be interpreted as a file name.  Automake *especially* attributes no special significance to the Unicode single-character elipsis, such as appears in your example.

Overall, I'm inclined to guess that the `Makefile.am` fragment presented in the question in fact is not drawn from a working Automake input file at all, but instead copied verbatim from an example in a book or tutorial, where the elipses are not meant to be taken as literal file content.

Comment: I can attest that the Makefile.am is in fact a working input file. Removing the unicode ellipses seems to have no effect at all.

Comment: Has no effect *on what*, @JacobGeigle?  There is a variety of reasons why you might see no difference in your build, starting from the fact that `Makefile.am` may well not be directly involved in the build at all.  But that's really beside the point.  The question was about the significance of the elipses to Automake, and the answer is as given: no special significance at all.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I was merely trying to clarify that the code snippet above is the entire file for a particular source directory, that is optionally built and no errors are given by autoreconf / configure / make with them present. Removing them and restarting the build process from autoreconf proceeds with no discernible changes. I was surprised that since they don't have a special meaning, they didn't cause an error.